# Generics with contravariant type parameters and Unity container

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an interface with contravariant type parameter, say `IFoo`:

```
interface IFoo<in T> {}
```

Now I have three classes:

```
class B {}

class D : B {}

class Foo : IFoo<B> {}
```

If I register them like this

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo<B>, Foo>();
```

...then try to resolve `IFoo<D>`, it fails because I didn't really register `IFoo<D>` or `IFoo<>`
. It's clear.

My current solution is just iterate over `Registrations`, find the registration which `RegisteredType` is assignable from resolving type (`IFoo<D>` in my case) then resolve its `MappedToType` type.

The question is simple: is there a better way to do this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

A little more context.

I have some kind of mapper.

```
IMapper<in TSource, in TDest> : IMapper // IMapper is non-generic
{
    void Map(TSource source, TDest dest);
}
```

And I want to register only base mapper (where `TSource` is `IEnumerable<T>`) and be able to resolve this mapper for every type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, for example for `T[]`:

```
object source = GetSource(); // runtime type is T[]
object dest = GetDest();

Type mapperType = typeof(IMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(source.GetType(), dest.GetType());
IMapper mapper = (IMapper) container.Resolve(mapperType);
mapper.Map(source, dest);
```

And yes, I'm interested only in Unity/C#-based approaches...

Comment: Maybe a better way is to implement a Unity extension registering a BuilderStrategy doing that.

Comment: Switch to a different framework?

Comment: Why would you try to resolve IFoo<D> without registering it? Is the registering or resolution somehow dynamic?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: you want to register only IFoo<? extends B> to register all kind of subclasses at once. In the future might you have other subclasses and you want that to work out of the box. It also saves the number of classes to register.

Comment: Register all interfaces to a single implementation? Why wouldn't you register one and resolve one if there is only one implementation to be registered? Sorry for bothering but I can't still think of a scenario where this could really be useful. If D and other classes inherit from B and all of them map to the same implementation, I would always resolve with the base IFoo<B>.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: There are scenarios where this makes sense (although rare). But handling of business events come to mind using `IEventHandler<TEvent>` or when doing messaging with versioned messages for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I suppose Unity can be extended to enable resolving variance typing as @onof said in his comment (although I don't know how), but when you want to do this, please read this article about [enabling variance support in your container](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=90). Although the article is about a different container, it discusses some general problems that you will encounter independently of the container of choice.

Comment: In that case do I consider it best to delete my answer, before it gets all votes down. I tried to help from a different perspective. Good luck to you all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to resolve the same Mapper every time. If that's right, and IEnumerable<> is the only interface that your mapper needs to deal with, then your approach seems like it's a bit overkill.

I would try registering the mapper using non-generic `IEnumerable()`, instead of `IEnumerable<T>` (`container.RegisterType<IFoo<IEnumerable>, Foo>();`).  If I remember correctly, a generic `IEnumerable<T>` can be passed to a non-generic `IEnumerable()` parameter, so you don't need to worry about what type parameter is passed.  So when you go to resolve your mapper, you shouldn't even need to check the type, just resolve `IMapper<IEnumerable>`.

The following code compiled:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {            
            IEnumerable<int> coll = new int[0];
            IEnumerable coll2 = coll;

         var blah = new Test<IEnumerable<int>>();
    }
}

public interface ITest<in T> where T : IEnumerable
{
}

public class Test<T> : ITest<T> where T : IEnumerable { }
```

If you need to get different implementations of `IMapper`, then that's another story.  In that case, you have to register each implementation.